# How can I avoid OOM issue while writing huge dataframes in orc format using PySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have two scripts: a and b. In script 'a', two CSV files are read into two data frames and then joined into a resulting data frame which is then written to a CSV file. This task does not end up in OOM issue and is very fast: 8-9 minutes for 1 billion rows, 100 columns, 41.2 GB CSV files each.

The other script, 'b', is similar to 'a' in every aspect but one: writing format. The input files are the same: 1B rows, 100 cols, 41.2 GB csv files. This script saves the resulting data frame in an ORC format. It then results in an error:

```
An error occurred while calling o91.orc. Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 36 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 36.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 800, ip-*-*-*-*.ap-south-1.compute.internal, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

The code for csv reading to orc is:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader, DataFrameWriter
from datetime import datetime

import time

# @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

print("All imports were successful.")


df = spark.read.csv(
    's3://****',
    header=True
)
print("First dataframe read with headers set to True")

df2 = spark.read.csv(
    's3://****',
    header=True
)

print("Second data frame read with headers set to True")

# Obtain columns lists
left_cols = df.columns
right_cols = df2.columns

# Prefix each dataframe's field with "left_" or "right_"
df = df.selectExpr([col + ' as left_' + col for col in left_cols])
df2 = df2.selectExpr([col + ' as right_' + col for col in right_cols])

# Perform join
# df3 = df.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='l.left_c_0' == 'r.right_c_0')

# df3 = df.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='c_0')

df3 = df.join(
    df2,
    df["left_column_test_0"] == df2["right_column_test_0"]
)

print("Dataframes have been joined successfully.")
output_file_path = 's3://****

df3.write.orc(
    output_file_path
)

# print("Dataframe has been written to csv.")
job.commit()
```

My csv file is in this way:

```
0,1,2,3,4,.....99
1,2,3,4,......100
2,3,4,5,......101
.
.
.
.
[continues until the 1 billionth row]
```

How do I ensure that my code does not cause any OOM error?

Comment: I am not familiar with the ORC format but I guess the best approach would be to write it row by row. Something on these lines:

`with open('yourORCfile', 'wb') as f:
        for row in df3:
             f.write(row)`

Comment: @Gio, you know, that is not working while using S3. It yields an error: `no such file or directory`.

Comment: are you sure the path is written correctly? At work I have to use:

`with open('\\\servername\\userhome\\user\\folder\\asubfolder\\mydata.csv', 'r') as f:`

(this is to read a file)

Comment: That path doesn't exist yet, the file will be written and then that path would exist. That is how things work in S3.  That is how I have written other orc and csv (any file) files until now. The issue arises when I use `with open`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that =). Is there a way to create the path by writing an empty file and then fill it up later?

Comment: I am on it, will create a dummy object and then write using with open. Although, I fear this row by row would be too slow to consider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189956/discussion-between-gio-and-aviral-srivastava).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to recover from OOM issues, I had to re-partition it. The logic in doing so is that each partition would be surely under OOM(given my data).

The code for this is:
`df3 = df3.repartition("left_column_test_0")`

Although, for ORC file format, spark took a lot more time: 29 minutes. I am still looking into reasons why orc is slower than csv for spark.